# Autofac Multiple Regsistrations to Single service. Simple Injector -> Autofac translation

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, autofac, cqrs, autofac-module

I've developed a CQRS style database access framework based on Tripod and other inspirations but targeting .NET Standard and simplifying for easier use. I want to split the IoC into separate integration packages so consumers can get the type registration I'm currently doing internally easily without being locked into a specific IoC container. My issue is I've only really worked closely with SimpleInjector so not familiar with other systems and their nuances around how they handle specific scenarios. I have an iminent need to support Autofac so thought I'd try here to see if anyone can translate.

I have the following Simple Injector CompositionRoot static class:

```
public static void RegisterDatabase(this Container container, DbContextOptions<EntityDbContext> dbContextOptions, params Assembly[] assemblies)
{
    var scopedLifeStyle = container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle;

    //container.Register<ICreateDbModel, DefaultDbModelCreator>(scopedLifeStyle); // lifestyle c
    container.RegisterInitializer<EntityDbContext>( //(container.InjectProperties);
        handlerToInitialise => handlerToInitialise.ModelCreator = new DefaultDbModelCreator()
    );

    // Setup DbContext
    var ctxReg = scopedLifeStyle.CreateRegistration(
        () => new EntityDbContext(dbContextOptions),
        container);

    container.AddRegistration<IUnitOfWork>(ctxReg);
    container.AddRegistration<IReadEntities>(ctxReg);
    container.AddRegistration<IWriteEntities>(ctxReg);
}
```

In ASP.NET Core solutions I invoke the above from Startup.Configure(...) with:

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<EntityDbContext>()
    //.UseInMemoryDatabase("Snoogans");
    .UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
container.RegisterDatabase(optionsBuilder.Options);
```

which allows me to switch out to an in memory database for unit testing if needed. EntityDbContext contains all my unit of work methods for calling onto the context without having to specify explicit DbSet for each table. The IUnitOfWork, IReadEntities and IWriteEntities interfaces all define methods on the EntityDbContext.

So I'm not sure how I'd go about making an Autofac module that allows scoped registration of the dbcontext with passed in DbContextOptions followed by multiple registrations of interfaces to this registration.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Comment: Have you tried using the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection registrations to keep everything agnostic instead of having individual IoC integration packages?Autofac has Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection to translate those; and other support that, too. Might save you time.

Comment: Yeah I really don't like it to be honest. I'll use it for some basic stuff like the controllers setup and loggin, but I prefer to CrossWire with SI and use the Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection package to return an IServiceProvider wrapping AutoFac. The way I'm looking at this is that not everyone uses the same system and if they want my framework to be useable then they should be able to integrate. If I just use the builtin DI then they have to stuff around to make it work or just give up. I want to provide integration packages to help people out with whatever they want to use

Comment: Using `IServiceCollection` doesn't mean you're using the built in DI. You can use that for _registrations only_ - a common format for a "module" that DI frameworks can read using their existing adapters - and then build the DI container using the specific DI framework. It would mean you write your registrations ONCE and everyone gets the benefit of the common format while still using their preferred container (assuming it has an adapter, which many do.) But it looks like you figured it out, so maybe this is moot.

Comment: @TravisIllig Thanks for the reply. Is it viable to bake in my own DI using autofac but still allow through this interface the callers to use their own for other functionality using any other IoC system? My goal is for this packaged library to be usable in any system without locking them in, so they could use structuremap, simple injector, ninject or whatever. My intial thought ws to make other nuget package which were external but do the registration wiring and return the container. But with that I'd need to provide integration packages for all DI systems out there, or others could do it.

Comment: The point of MS DI abstractions is to be the common registration layer and let any container back it. A quick search shows Autofac, StructureMap, Lamar, Unity, and some others support this sort of integration. Sort of like if you use the MS logger interface it can be backed by supporting frameworks; you don't need to maintain 10 different integration libraries, the common interface does it for you.

Comment: But my point is do they clash or play nice through these abstractions if there’s multiple?

Comment: It's not clear what "clash if there's multiple" means. I think it's worth you taking some time to _just try it_ - create a small project that has common registrations and a couple of unit test projects, one for each DI framework you like. Try it, see what works and what doesn't. A little research now may save you a lot of maintenance long term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out the process and now have an AutoFac module. I was able to registermodule by instance of the class and also pass in the options when I instantiate. Because EntityDbContext implements the three interfaces I was registering separately in the Simple Injector scenario, AutoFac has the convenience of being able to just infer them and register with AsImplementedInterfaces()

```
public class EntityFrameworkModule : Module
    {
        private readonly DbContextOptions<EntityDbContext> _dbContextOptions;

        public EntityFrameworkModule(DbContextOptions<EntityDbContext> dbContextOptions)
        {
            _dbContextOptions = dbContextOptions;

        }

        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            // If the calling code hasn't already registered a custom 
            // ICreateDbModel then register the internal DefaultDbModelCreator
            builder.RegisterType<DefaultDbModelCreator>()
                .IfNotRegistered(typeof(ICreateDbModel))
                .As<ICreateDbModel>();

            // Expecting IUnitOfWork, IReadEntities and IWriteEntities to be registered with this call
            builder.Register(c => new EntityDbContext(_dbContextOptions)
                {
                    ModelCreator = c.Resolve<ICreateDbModel>()
                })
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        }
    }
```